# I can't plot the kernel density estimation of an Inverse gamma(0.001, 0.001) in matlab

Tags: matlab, inverse, gamma-distribution

I am trying to plot the ksdensity of an Inverse `gamma(0.001, 0.001)` but the plot has only one point. The commands I used are

```
 alpha1 = 0.001;
    beta1 = 0.001;
    n = 1e+5;
    r=1./gamrnd(alpha1,1/beta1,n,1);  
   [f,xi] = ksdensity(r);
    plot(xi,f,'--m');
```

The first term of `f` is a real number and all the others are `NaN`. The first term of `xi` is a real number and all the others are `Inf`.

Could you please me help me with this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the generated data in `r`? I get almost 49 % of the time the value `Inf`. It appears that many values of the Gamma distribution with the parameters you chose are 0, or actually, so small that they cannot be represented in the standard double precision numeric format of Matlab (the smallest possible value is 2.225 · 10^-308).

If you look at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) for the inverse Gamma distribution, you will see that the mean is not defined for alpha <= 1 and the variance is not defined for alpha <= 2, etc. According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+gamma+distribution+%280.001%2C+0.001%29), the mode of your distribution is at 0.000999001, while the median is at 1.90687 · 10^298 (only a few orders of magnitude below the largest possible double value, 1.797 · 10^308!).

The density around the mode

```
x = 0.0001:0.0001:0.1;
plot(x, beta1 ^ alpha1 / gamma(alpha1) .* x .^ -(alpha1 + 1) .* exp(- beta1 ./ x))
```

looks like this

[image]

but this covers only a tiny fraction of the total distribution (the 1st percentile is at 41.2211).

So the problem here is not the kernel density estimation, but that the distribution you are looking at has extreme properties which make it hard to plot the density from the analytical formula, let alone estimate it from simulated random numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have no idea how you helped me.

Comment: @F.F., glad I could help! :-)